# Add component css to React.js, 'App' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, frontend

I've started to learn react by creating a new class App that extends Component, but i found it hard on understanding the concept such as codes below, but I am not sure how do I wrap the codes with extended class component and the methods when it returning the error as 'App' is defined but never used no-unused-vars. Thanks advance for your help and explanation!

App.js

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  Component,
} from 'react';
import PokemonList from './PokemonList'
import axios from 'axios'
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import './App.css';



function App() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])
  const [currentPageUrl, setCurrentPageUrl] = useState("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
  const [nextPageUrl, setNextPageUrl] = useState()
  const [prevPageUrl, setPrevPageUrl] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    let cancel
    axios.get(currentPageUrl, {
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then(res => {
      setLoading(false)
      setNextPageUrl(res.data.next)
      setPrevPageUrl(res.data.previous)
      setPokemon(res.data.results.map(p => p.name))
    })

    return () => cancel()
  }, [currentPageUrl])

  function gotoNextPage() {
    setCurrentPageUrl(nextPageUrl)
  }

  function gotoPrevPage() {
    setCurrentPageUrl(prevPageUrl)
  }

  if (loading) return "Loading..."

   if (loading) return "Loading..."

   return ( <>
     <PokemonList pokemon = {
       pokemon}/> <
     Pagination gotoNextPage = {
       nextPageUrl ? gotoNextPage : null
     }
     gotoPrevPage = {
       prevPageUrl ? gotoPrevPage : null
     }/> </>
   );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to add extend the component class and the rendered method with nested elements as below so i can do some styling,

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add `export default App;` under the class component

Comment: @Taki i did, i just wanted to know how to implement the stying code into app.js :)